# CIAreaHistogram does not return expected result

Tags: ios, swift, histogram, core-image, cifilter

I want to get the `CIAreaHistogram` of a `UIImage`.

Below I copy the code I run.  The `print()` statement currently prints 255 lines with `0.0 0.0 0.0` followed by the last line being `0.0 0.0 0.058823529`.

My `UIImage` input is also displayed on screen, so I'm sure there is an image.

I've also tried this filter in the CIFilter.io app.  Strangely enough, given a colourful input image, the output image was a single tint grey line.  Of course I expected a line, but not the solid grey.

What could I be doing wrong?

```
let inputImage = CIImage(cgImage: outputImage!.cgImage!)
let histogramFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaHistogram", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey : inputImage,
                                                                     "inputExtent" : inputImage.extent,
                                                                     "inputScale" : NSNumber(value: 1.0),
                                                                     "inputCount" : NSNumber(value: 256)])!

func processHistogram(ciImage: CIImage)
{
    let image = renderImage(ciImage: ciImage)

    for x in 0 ... 255
    {
        getPixelColor(fromCGImage: (image?.cgImage!)!, pos: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
    }
}

func getPixelColor(fromCGImage cgImage: CGImage, pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor
{
    let pixelData = cgImage.dataProvider!.data
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(cgImage.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    print("\(r) \(g) \(b)")

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}

func renderImage(ciImage: CIImage) -> UIImage?
{
    var outputImage: UIImage?
    let size = ciImage.extent.size

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    {
        context.interpolationQuality = .high
        context.setShouldAntialias(true)

        let inputImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
        inputImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

        outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    return outputImage
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this Q&A? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613936/ciareahistogram-gives-me-all-0-except-the-last-element

Comment: Be sure to render the the outputImage of the histogramFilter to an un-premutiplied destination.  This is because that image also contains the histogram of the alpha channel. The easiest way is to use `[CIRenderDestination initWithBitmapData:width:height:bytesPerRow:format:kCIFormatRGBAh]` and set the `.alphaMode` to `CIRenderDestinationAlphaUnpremultiplied`.